# How to stop Tailwind CSS from purging the classes in local development environment?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I am `vite.js` build tool, `vue.js` and `tailwindcss: ^2.1.4`

Everything was working normal before but now I am not sure what I did, purge is not working as expected. Tailwind class started purging even in my development environment. It was suppose to purge only when I build project for production.

Say that I applied `mb-10 pt-10` to div, to see this in effect, I need to do one of two things:

1. Restart vite.js, Or
2. In css file define: `.cust-class { @apply mb-10 pt-10 }` then `mb-10 pt-10` classes will work (together or individually)

Here is my `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: '#000',
      white: '#fff',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I never had issue with same configuration in other projects.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was due to .env file, which I added recently:

There I have defined

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

I changed it to

```
NODE_ENV=development
```

things are working now.